# Comparing two rasters in scatter plot with different resolutions using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, resampling

I have 2 rasters taken from 2 cameras with different resolution over the same field. One shows NDVI values, the other is temperature. I need to make a scatter plot between these rasters but they have different cell sizes due to resolution of the camera and various number of rows/columns.

I tried Resample in Arcmap 10.5. to resize the smaller raster but it will not get the exact cell size and number of rows/col.

How can I compare 2 rasters with different resolutions if resampling function does not work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract all values of a raster](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/333776/how-to-extract-all-values-of-a-raster)

Comment: Do you still want to extract pixel values as a table? I can post an answer to that

Comment: Yes, I do, but I figured my main question is if there is a way to actually compare these 2 rasters directly. If there is no way for this, I think I should extract pixel values anyway. I would appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract pixel values as table you can use arcpy. Adjust and execute in python window:

```py
import arcpy
import numpy as np

in_raster = r'C:\GIS\data\someraster.jp2' #Change
out_table = r'C:\GIS\Default.gdb\rastertable' #Change

arr = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(in_raster) #Create array
structured_array = np.core.records.fromrecords(arr) #Convert to structured array which is required for NumPyArrayToTable
arcpy.da.NumPyArrayToTable(structured_array, out_table) #Create table
```